# java.lang.nullpointerexception for ContentResolver

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to use **ContentResolver** along with my ContentProvider project that can be found in this [TutorialPoint Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm) and though I have followed the instructions of this [Tutorial](http://marakana.com/s/post/1375/android_content_provider_tutorial) but yet i'm not able to run the project, I'm expecting the whole saved data in the ContentProvider to be listed in the textview.

**MainActivity.java of ContentResolver**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        /* Content Resolver Declaration */
        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        String[] projection = new String[]{BaseColumns._ID,UserDictionary.Words.WORD};
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                long id = cursor.getLong(0);
                String word = cursor.getString(1);
                txtView.setText(id+"--"+word);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
}           
    }
```

**AndoridManifest.XML of Content Resolver**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mycontentresolver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:sharedUserId="com.example.mycontentprovider" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mycontentresolver.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**activity_main.XML of ContentResolver**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mycontentresolver.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/largeTxt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**ContentProvider Package + Provider**

```
package com.example.mycontentprovider;

public class StudentsProvider extends ContentProvider {

   static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.example.provider.College";
   static final String URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/students";
```

**StackTrace**

```
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790): Process: com.example.mycontentresolver, PID: 4790
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mycontentresolver/com.example.mycontentresolver.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2514)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1069)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:885)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1952)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at com.example.mycontentresolver.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:14)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
06-11 01:01:50.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     ... 11 more
```

I tried many solutions provided with vary attempts but I believe there's something missing in my code and need to be fixed, Appreciate your responses.

**UPDATE: I have fixed the first issue according for the solutions below and that is the new TrackTrace modified  + the Name of the ContentProvider if it does help or have to be changed + and I have AppCombat v7_6 in my libraries for support by default.**

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: Apologize forget, added.

Comment: What is line 14 of MainActivity? There is were the error is

Comment: Line 14 is initializing for Textview.   `TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);` <br/> and no errors in the layout file nor the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Your current problem has nothing to do with your ContentResolver.

```
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

You can only call `findViewById` (successfully) once `setContentView` has been called. In your case you're trying to call findViewById when the class is instantiated which will cause your crash. Move your `findViewById` call into your `onCreate` to fix this

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Such silly mistake I did, anyhow I fixed it but yet I'm receiving errors; I have updated the post regarding the new problem; appreciate your response and help.

Answer (score 1):

Find your `TextView` after `setContentView()`.

Like this :

```
TextView txtViewl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtViewl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    ....

}
```

Comment: Such silly mistake I did, anyhow I fixed it but yet I'm receiving errors; I have updated the post regarding the new issue; appreciate your response and help.